# How to decrease the space between components in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to decrease the space between components (DIV mainly) from 20px to 3px or maybe 5px. I know that I need to multiply 12 columns * 60 px and then 11 spaces * 20 px and this give me 940px. Also knows about the tool from Twitter to make those changes but I tried and my styles still gettin 20px of space. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You mean the grid columns?  The values you want to change are:

`@gridColumns`

`@gridColumnWidth`

`@gridGutterWidth`

You can modify them in the LESS scripts or you can [download the entire package with the variables already customized](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variables).